# Use of connecting capacitor in I to V converter

Tags: operational-amplifier

This is the suggested circuit for Trans impedance amplifier for 7721.

[image: Circuit Diagram]

I will be using this as current to voltage converter. I wish to know why the capacitor Cf is connected in parallel with the feedback resistor though the textbooks give circuit diagram of I-V converter with feedback resistor only? And why generally we put capacitors with the power supplies?

Comment: it will work with just the resistor, but the capacitor allows for some output filtering, specifically the whole thing acts as a low-pass filter and transimpedance amplifier

Comment: Is it there for quick output settling purpose or something like that?

Comment: It depends on your appliction, In my experience I've used transimpedance amps to convert photodiode current for recording in a data acquisition type set up, you can, for instance, use it to filter out high frequency flicker from flourescent lights, useful if you are looking for low frequency signals from your photodiode. YOu could of course use a filter on the output, but this just saves components

Comment: Actually I plan to use it for flicker noise reduction of PicoAmp source. So first after getting the voltage signal I'll be using three LPFs in cascade to reduce the noise further. You think it will serve the purpose?

Comment: There are many ways to shape the bandwidth of your amp for the signals you are looking for, Depending on the relative amplitude of the flicker and the desired signal this may be enough.If there is only light transient flicker on a large low f signal, this may be enough, if the flicker is much stronger than the signal frequency you may need a sharper response filter

Comment: And why do we use those capacitors with power supply?

Comment: Think of it this way, the opamp will provide whatever voltage is needed (up to the supply) in order to maintain V = IR across that resistor, for DC signals, the capacitor is basically an open wire so it sees the entire Rf+Ra, for high frequency signals, the impedance is greatly decreased as the impedance of the capacitor approaches zero.

Comment: To avoid prolonged discussion I'll move it to an answer

Comment: Technically, the capacitor doesn't act as a low pass filter. Rather, it reduces the circuit's gain at high frequency. The end result is the same, but you can think of them in slightly different terms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic transimpedance amplifier is, as you've properly stated, just a simple resistor feedback.

[image]

The opamp, in a simplistic model, will source the voltage on the output necessary to drop your I_in across R. For DC or near-DC signals you only care about the resistance R when setting your gain factor. AC signals being sent across the transimpedance amp will see  a slightly different picture.

Internally, the opamp has some capacitance between the input and ouput nodes. This establishes the maximum bandwidth of the op-amp. Doing nothing (jsut leaving the resistor) you will see that frequencies above the Gain Bandwidth Product of your opamp (17mhz for yours) will be shunted. However, often times its useful to shape the bandwidth of you amplifier in order to filter out signals that are undesirable, placing a capacitor across the feedback reduces the impedance seen by high frequency signals and thus reduces its ouput gain relative to the dc level signal (which only sees the resistor as a feedback current path). Thus you have a basic LP filter built into your transimpedance amplifier. Additionally, as was pointed out in the comments, many common sources used in conjunction with transimpedance amps (like photodiodes) have their own internal capacitance which act as their own filter and can change the frequency response even in the operating range, by placing a capacitor across the feedback you can have a more predictable frequency response and essentially take the capacitance of the source out of the picture.

The power supply capacitors are known as "decoupling capacitors" they serve several purposes.

- They filter the power supply from high frequency transients and coupled noise by providing them a low impedance path to ground
- They act as a electron "bucket", When the opamp swings from one end to another it starts drawing current from the power-supply lines, the power supply doesn't respond immediately, and stray inductances on the power supply line can prevent the opamp from drawing the current it needs and the voltage will drop. Like a backup battery the capacitance will provide the op-amp with its instantaneous power requirements as its current demands increase, as such they are usually placed as close as possible to opamp when laying out the circuit

Often times you will see two capacitors in parallel to ground. One high valued capacitor to act as the "backup" and another low-valued capacitor as the HF shunt to ground. WHile this may seem pointless (if capacitors add in parallel why not just use a larger one?) it has its benefits, while the capacitance of the capacitors adds in parallel, their small (but finite) resistance (from the wire leads) will be reduced and more importantly, as was pointed out in the comments, the inductance will also be reduced. So the impedance to ground for HF signals is much lower with two individual capacitors vs one larger one. If no HF supply filtering is needed, a larger capacitor alone is enough,

Comment: wow! +1. really a great answer! thanks.

Comment: There's a couple of things here. Two caps in parallel on power lines - it's the self inductance of larger caps that cause them to become generally like inductors above a certain frequency that is the problem - not series resistance. Adding a feedback cap counters the self-capacitance of sources (like photodiodes) that connect to thes circuits that can cause large peaks in the frequency response. Also a lot of IV convertors have longer leads attached to sources which also have bigger capacitance.